# Android Application lister

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I have created an app that I want to list all the installed applications to to a custom listview. bt unfortunately the activity crashes at the start! can any one please help me on this! I cant find the error, since it does not give any!

AppActivity.java

```
package com.ex.layout;

import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AppActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener{

String[] name = getaAppName();
String[] packs = getPackName();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ListView li = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.applist);
    ListviewAdapet list = new ListviewAdapet(this, name, packs);
    li.setAdapter(list);
    li.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long id) {  
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    Toast.makeText(this,"Title => "+name[position]+"=> n Description"+packs[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
}  

public String[] getaAppName() {
    List<PackageInfo> apps = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
    String appname[] = new String[apps.size()];
    for (int number = 0; number < apps.size(); number++) {
        PackageInfo pack = apps.get(number);
        appname[number] = pack.applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString();
    }
    return appname;
}

public String[] getPackName(){
    List<PackageInfo> apps = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
    String packnames[] = new String[apps.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < apps.size(); i++) {
        PackageInfo pack = apps.get(i);
        packnames[i] = pack.packageName;
    }
    return packnames;
}

}
```

this is the next class! it extends baseadapter to get the output.
listviewadapet.java

```
package com.ex.layout;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ListviewAdapet extends BaseAdapter{

Activity context;
String[] appname , packname;

public ListviewAdapet(Activity Context, String[] appname , String[] packname) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    super();
    this.appname = appname;
    this.packname = packname;
    this.context = Context;

}

public class Viewholder{
    TextView appname;
    TextView packname;
}

public int getCount(String[] array) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int count = array.length;
    return count;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Viewholder view;
    LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null);
        view = new Viewholder();
        view.appname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.appname);
        view.packname= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.packagename);
        convertView.setTag(view);
    } else {
        view = (Viewholder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    view.appname.setText(appname[position]);
    view.packname.setText(packname[position]);
    return convertView;
}

public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

}
```

Please help me on this! 
Thank you.

Comment: Do you have the necessary permissions in the app's manifest?

Comment: I'm a newbie to android programming! so I have no idea what is stack trace! how can I get the stack trace. m using eclipse

Comment: every time I run the project, I get the message layout has stopped.

I have not given permissions. I had another project which did the same thing bt I dint give any permissions. that project was a simple one, which I take the installed applications as a list nd direct it to a standard listview. not a custom one. In this project I want to customize the listview.

Comment: Maybe you should consider that what you're trying to do is outside of your depth and reconsider. :) You need a gentler simpler exercises first, understanding Android, understanding Eclipse, the Android-SDK, Java. Copying/pasting from elsewhere is not going to help.

Comment: I can't reconsider and change what I do since it is a research project that I have got from my university. I went through lot of tutorials and I'm like crashed inside of my mind! :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have done two serious errors in code.

Error 1

```
String[] name = getaAppName();
String[] packs = getPackName();
```

You are calling these two methods before onCreate.REMEMBER `getPackageManager` needs Activity context.If you define it before onCreate you will get damn `NullPointerException`

So change your code

from

```
public class AppActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener{

String[] name = getaAppName();
String[] packs = getPackName();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

To

```
public class AppActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener{

    String[] name;
    String[] packs;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        name = getaAppName();
        packs = getPackName();
```

Error 2

```
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}
```

You will get Empty list if you return 0 here.

So change it to

```
public int getCount() {
        return packname.length;
    }
```

Comment: I corrected the errors that you pointed out, and cleaned the project. then When I run the project, the main activity just starts and the list is not shown. there is a textview I've defined in the main.xml file and it is the only thing that shows up. :(